# Preventing line break in a displayquote environment

Tags: luatex, koma-script, fontspec

In the text I am writing I make extensive use of blockquotes, which I need to refer back to at a later point (kind of like numbered theorems, really). I use `displayquote` for this purpose, and it works pretty much as expected. (The referring part is also taken care of, using `\label`)

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,BCOR=8mm]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[main=ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[silent]{fontspec}                   \setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\usepackage{setspace}                           
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}            

\usepackage{etoolbox}                           \newcounter{quote}

    \AtBeginEnvironment{displayquote}{\refstepcounter{quote}\singlespace\vspace{-.5em}\small\itshape}
    \AtEndEnvironment{displayquote}    {\hfill\rlap{\scriptsize\normalfont[\thequote]}\vspace{-.5em}\endsinglespace}

\begin{document}

A bit of dummy text here to get us started, followed by the first quote:

\begin{displayquote}
Bei [Gastmann] ist das Böse nicht der Ausdruck einer Philosophie oder eines Triebes, sondern seiner Freiheit: der Freiheit des Nichts. (S.~109) \end{displayquote}

Not an issue; the quote is formatted as desired, and the counter is displayed.

\begin{displayquote}Als jahrelanger Gesandter Argentiniens in China genieße er das Vertrauen der fremden Macht und als ehemaliger Verwaltungspräsident des Blechtrusts jenes der Industriellen.~(S.~73f.)
\end{displayquote}

In this case, however, [2] is shown in the next line. This must be prevented, even at the cost of bleeding into the right margin.

\end{document}
```

If I have a longer quote that fills the last line, however, my quote counter is shown in the next line, all by itself. I would like to prevent that from happening.

[image]
I am using LuaTeX, by the way. Not using `fontspec` seems to solve this issue, but is not an option for obvious reasons.

Comment: Unfortunately this returns an `Infinite glue shrinkage found in a paragraph.` error for every quote.

Comment: Okay, no problem.  Removing the suggestion so that it doesn't foul someone else up.  You might instead try `\unskip\nobreak\hfill`.  The `\nobreak` should avoid a new line with only the number, but it might (1) bring down some text to the next line, or (2) give an overfull `\hbox` with the number in the margin.

Comment: It's *very* hard to ask TeX to do bad typesetting.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thank you very much, that does (with very minor variations) indeed what I was trying to accomplish. If you'd care to make your comment an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being able to test this myself (don't have all the required packages and fonts available), I suggest "dropping back" to a basic TeX approach.  This is *not* generally recommended.  Only one definition needs to be revised:

```
\AtEndEnvironment{displayquote}    {\hfill\rlap{\scriptsize\normalfont[\thequote]}\vspace{-.5em}\endsinglespace}
```

In order to suppress the linebreak, it is necessary to overcome the space that may be inserted if `\end{displayquote}` is input on a new line.  `\unskip` will accomplish this, and `\nobreak` will prevent (La)TeX from proceeding to a new line.  It may be helpful (so that the number will be clearly separated from the end of the quote) to insert a small fixed space.  Thus the following is suggested as the replacement for the first part of the definition:

```
\AtEndEnvironment{displayquote}    {\unskip\nobreak\,\hfill ...
```

*Never* leave a blank line before `\end{displayquote}`.  That will always force the number to a new line -- `\unskip` works only in horizontal mode.